# Change jqplot renderer to LogAxisRenderer on button press

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I'm putting together a small web app that updates a jqPlot line chart data with a call to a rest api and possibly changes the scale of the axis when a button in a form is pressed. In the minimal reproduction below, the new data from /app/call gets plotted, but the axis scale doesn't change. What confuses me is the label does change from 'foo' to 'bar'.

Any idea as to what's going on?

Thanks!

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[null]], {
          axes : {
            xaxis : {
              label: 'foo'
            }
          }
        });
    });
</script>

<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#buttonID').click(function() {
      // construct url
      var jsonurl = "/app/call/";

      $.get( jsonurl, function (data ) {
         var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         $.jqplot ('chart1', [jsonData], {
           axes : {
             xaxis : {
               label: 'bar',
               renderer : $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer
               }
             }
          }).replot();
       });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was something simple that got left out. The plugin for the log axis wasn't included as a script.

Adding:

solved the issue.